# Understanding ruby quine

Tags: ruby, heredoc, quine

I have found this code block on Wikipedia as an example of a quine (program that prints itself) in Ruby.

```
puts <<2*2,2
puts <<2*2,2
2
```

However, I do not get how it works. Especially, what I do not get is that when I remove the last line, I get this error:

> syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END

What happens in those lines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<<something` syntax begins a *here-document*, borrowed from UNIX shells via Perl - it's basically a multiline string literal that starts on the line after the `<<` and ends when a line starts with `something`.

So structurally, the program is just doing this:

```
puts str*2,2
```

... that is, print two copies of `str` followed by the number 2.

But instead of the variable `str`, it's including a literal string via a here-document whose ending sentinel is also the digit 2:

```
puts <<2*2,2
puts <<2*2,2
2
```

So it prints out two copies of the string `puts <<2*2,2`, followed by a 2.  (And since the method used to print them out is `puts`, each of those things gets a newline appended automatically.)

Comment: But if the end marker of the string is the "something" after `<<`, shouldn't it be `2*2,2` sequence then, and the same sequence used in the last line to end it?

Comment: The precedence of `<<` is tighter than `*`, so `<<2*2` is "the string represented by the following 2-terminated here document, multiplied by 2" rather than "the string represented by the following 2*2-terminated here document."

Answer (score 2):

In ruby, you can define strings with

```
str = <<DELIMITER
  long string
  on several
  lines
DELIMITER
```

I suppose that from here, you can guess the rest :)